# tkinter: Clicks in transparent shapes don't register

Tags: python, tkinter

Fairly simple one, this. For example:

```
a = canvas.create_circle(0,0,50,50,outline='red',width=3,fill='')
b = canvas.create_circle(0,0,50,50,outline='red',width=3,fill='red')
```

`b` will respond to click events anywhere in the circle, whereas `a` will only respond to clicks on the outline.

Is there a better way to solve this than simply using an almost-transparent colour for the fill?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends somewhat on how you define "better". It is true that clicks don't register if the objects don't have a fill color. One option is to put the click event on the canvas itself, then use the canvas `find_closest` or `find_overlapping` methods to find the object nearest the cursor.

Comment: This still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @jamylak: why does it not fix the problem? Are you saying that in your callback you're unable to find the nearest object?

Comment: `find_closest` doesn't work and `find_overlapping` doesn't return the oval with no fill. If you put on the fill everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You could use a polygon instead of an oval:

```
a = canvas.create_polygon(100,100,50,150,100,200,150,150, outline='red', fill='', smooth=1)
```

Edit:

A polygon is sensitive to mouse clicks even if it has no fill color (or outline for that matter).

see the canvas docs: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how does this solve the problem. Why is necessary to use a polygon?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but here is solution to the problem. In your case you can notice that if you click on the outline of the no fill object itself the click event will trigger.
(Don't know why but it behaves this way)

Now if you remove both the outline and fill i.e.

```py
a = canvas.create_circle(0,0,50,50,outline='',fill='')
```

The Invisible (no fill, no outline) will trigger the click event just like the other  circle 'b'.

So what you can do is create an invisible circle (no fill, no outline), Bind it to the trigger event.
Then create another circle right on top of it (same co-ordinates) with your desired outline parameters.

This will give the illusion of a single outlined circle with no fill and will still trigger the click event.